# React-Native: Facebook and Google Login

Tags: facebook-login, react-native, google-signin, react-native-ios

I am currently trying to implement Facebook and google login for a react-native app for ios and android. I must say, it is much less user-friendly than ionic for example. I have seen some libraries trying to implement this, but they all seem not to be maintained anymore.
Is there any common, reliable and stable solution that is easy to implement (if not easy to implement, really any solution that will work), to implement Facebook and/or Google login for react-native apps?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**For Google Login:**

I tried both https://github.com/devfd/react-native-google-signin and https://github.com/joonhocho/react-native-google-sign-in. And neither of them work properly! I'm doubted whether they're maintained anymore.

The final correct solution is https://github.com/fullstackreact/react-native-oauth. It has a very good installation guideline and worked very well for my project. It also supports auth with other providers like Facebook, Twitter, Slack, ...

Btw, **for Facebook Login**, https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk also works nicely, despite of complex installation.

Answer (score 2):

The [fbsdk](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk) is the best option for Facebook obviously.
For Google: I'm already using [react-native-google-signin](https://github.com/devfd/react-native-google-signin). It does (at least for Android) work as expected. It is a bit tricky to install, but there is a good [FAQ section](https://github.com/devfd/react-native-google-signin/blob/master/android-guide.md#faq) provided by the authors.

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-google-signin seems to be maintained well nowadays, and last week only I implemented it in a production react native app.

So would recommend that for Google authentication.

Answer (score 1):

Have you had an answer? I'm also finding a library to implement google auth in reactnative and did not find a suitable one. but for facebook login ,you can use [this](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk) .
Because it's made by facebook so I think it will be well maintained.

Comment: Thanks for the facebook link! :) It looks nice, but it still wants 'native implementation' (which is not further a problem actually..). Haven't found one for google yet.

Answer (score 1):

I tried using [react-native-oauth](https://github.com/fullstackreact/react-native-oauth). Maybe it was once a great option, but now the documentation on [github](https://github.com/fullstackreact/react-native-oauth) is outdated. The documentation says to use Identity Toolkit API, which has now shifted to Firebase, which already creates problems. From the [api home page](https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/):

> The newest version of Google Identity Toolkit has been released as
>   Firebase Authentication.
>
> New projects should use Firebase Authentication. To migrate an
>   existing project from Identity Toolkit to Firebase Authentication, see
>   the migration guide.

So the next I found was [react-native-google-signin](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-google-signin). It has a hefty procedure but [this](https://medium.com/@eloew47/react-native-android-google-login-with-native-modules-7b2595422992) medium article was a great help to implement it within minutes if you don't want to get into much detail.

For facebook, [fbsdk](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk) is the best one to use.

So the best options would be:
**Google**: [react-native-google-signin](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-google-signin)
**Facebook**: [fbsdk](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk)

Comment: Hey, the medium article is not a medium one, but a Google one. Is that a typo?

Answer (score 1):

You can consider using react-social-login. It supports Amazon, Facebook, GitHub, Google, Instagram and LinkedIn as providers. Please refer below link for more details.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-social-login